# Sending mail using swiftmailer but page become blank without any message

Tags: php, email, smtp, swiftmailer

I am sending mail using swiftmailer but no message send to receipt and page become blank without any message. i am using gmail smtp. nothing change in my php.ini file. is anything change is needed in my php.ini file. openssl.dll aleady unblock.please help me. this is urgent.if i want to use ip in the place of smtp.gmail.com then here i will change. here is my code

```
<?php
require_once 'lib/swift_required.php';
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com',465,'ssl');
$transport-> setUsername('my@gmail.com');
$transport-> setPassword('*******');
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance();
$message->setSubject($subject);
$message->setFrom(array($headers=>$myname));
$message->setTo($value);
$message->setBody($mail_body, 'text/plain');
$result = $mailer->send($message);
?>
```